# Liferay migration 5.3.2 to 6.2 Database changes

Tags: java, database, liferay

I am trying to migrate liferay from 5.3.2 to 6.2. As per the documents I understood that , it is not straight forward. First we need to migrate from 5.3.2 to 6.0.6 to 6.1 and finally to 6.2.

Now I just started to implement the steps to convert my liferay portal (5.3.2) to 6.0.6 as a first step.

My query is, in this process, will it change any schema or structure of the tables in a database in order to support the upgraded version?

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are database changes. Without more information about the actual setup, you'll find all information you need [in the documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/upgrading-lifer-4) (here for 6.0, that covers the upgrades).

The first start of a new Liferay version on the existing database will run the update scripts - permission assumed. If you don't want Liferay (or the application server) to have those permissions, you can download a standalone upgrade program, that must run with proper DDL permissions on the database.

Of course, this all assumes that you have a proper backup. Attention: You're only allowed to call it backup if you have demonstrated that you're actually able to restore it to a completely new system!

Once you're done with each single upgrade, you'll have to take care of your custom plugins and extensions. My take on the theme (which you probably have) is: Don't pay attention to it, just build a new one on 6.2, as you'll have two major theme-infrastructure updates between 5.2 and 6.0 (to AlloyUI) as well as between 6.1 and 6.2 (to bootstrap).

Comment: Just a side note: I was never able to successfully migrate 5.2 directly to 6.2, neither by installing the portal nor by using the database upgrade tool. It usually bombs out when it tries to migrate the document library.

Comment: Thank you Olaf Kock. The answer was useful. Now I am trying with another copy of the database. Hope I will be able to migrate it successfully.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's probably why the installation instructions advise to not attempt a direct update, instead go from version to version. After all, you'll run into problems right where they are created and can fix them close to their root - instead of running into followup problems introduced later.